# Sticky Sidebar that only sticks when sidebar bottom is at window bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I have a 2 column layout. The left column is way longer than the sidebar.  I want the sidebar only to stick when its bottom reaches the bottom of the browser window.  So the user can continue to scroll down the left column content while the right sidebar sticks.  I've seen a lot of sticky questions here, however this particular situation still stumps me.  I also have a sticking headline bar on the left column that i've successfully gotten to stick.

Here's a demo of what I've done in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwu56/Z9RJW/)!

and here's a quick look at the js I am trying out.

```
    $(function(){
       var headlineBarPos = $('.headlineBar').offset().top; // returns number
       var sidebarHeight = $('.sticky-sidebar-wrap').height();
       var sidebarTop = $('.sticky-sidebar-wrap').offset().top;
       var windowHeight = $(window).height();

       var totalHeight = sidebarHeight + sidebarTop;

    $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event 

          var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number

          // fixing the headline bar    
          if (headlineBarPos < windowTop) {
              $('.headlineBar').addClass('sticky').css('top', '0');
          }
          else {
              $('.headlineBar').removeClass('sticky').removeAttr('style');
          }

        if(sidebarHeight < windowTop) {
            $('.sticky-sidebar-wrap').addClass('sticky').css('top', '0');
        } else {
           $('.sticky-sidebar-wrap').removeClass('sticky').removeAttr('style');
        }

        console.log(windowTop);

    });


    console.log(headlineBarPos);
    console.log(sidebarHeight);
    console.log(sidebarTop);

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got it right, when the bottom of the sidebar comes into the view, then stick?

I created another div at the bottom of the sidebar (inside the sidebar).
When that comes into view, it sticks.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z9RJW/10/

```
<div class="moduleController"></div> //inside the sidebar
```

and in js

```
$(function () {


var headlineBarPos = $('.headlineBar').offset().top; // returns number
var moduleControllerPos = $('.moduleController').offset().top; // returns number    
var sidebarHeight = $('.sticky-sidebar-wrap').height();
var sidebarTop = $('.sticky-sidebar-wrap').offset().top;
var windowHeight = $(window).height();

var totalHeight = sidebarHeight + sidebarTop;

$(window).scroll(function () { // scroll event 

    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number

    // fixing the headline bar    
    if (headlineBarPos < windowTop) {
        $('.headlineBar').addClass('sticky').css('top', '0');
    } else {
        $('.headlineBar').removeClass('sticky').removeAttr('style');
    }

    if (moduleControllerPos < windowTop + windowHeight) {
        $('.sticky-sidebar-wrap').addClass('sticky').css('top', '0');
    } else {
$('.sticky-sidebar-wrap').removeClass('sticky').removeAttr('style');        }






    console.log(windowTop);

});


console.log(headlineBarPos);
console.log(sidebarHeight);
console.log(sidebarTop);
```

});

I hope it helps.

Comment: Very helpful indeed.  I made one minor tweak to your solution to get the behavior I am searching for - see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mwu56/TK5vf/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
if (sidebar.top + sidebar.height < window.scrolltop + window.height) {
    // set sticky
}
```

and set sticky needs to take into account that the sidebar may be higher than the viewport, so:

```
sidebar.top = sidebar.height - window.height // this will be a negative number
```